# Why is there a symlink frow www/ to public_html/ in Bluehost by default?

Tags: security, webserver

My internet sites are at the folder

> public_html

I noted that www/ seems to have a symbolic link to public_html.

I do not know why we need the www/ -folder, when we have public_html.
Perhaps, it is a security reason. Perhaps, the name of the folder where websites are should be hidden.

**Why does www/ -folder point to the folder public_html by default?**

Comment: You might want to clarify, is a symbolic link or hard link?

Comment: @Samuel: I am not completely sure. It is light blue in terminal.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a programming question. Here is their support forum: http://www.bluehostforums.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$HOME/public_html` is convention [for user dirs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/public_html.html), while `$HOME/www/domain` is typical convention for user domains in shared hosting. Having symlink you don't have to worry which one you use.

Comment: You still do have to worry though. Cookies for example. I think it's best to redirect from www

Comment: Yes, www is just a shortcut for public_html. The web hoster will configure the web server to serve up public_html to www.yourdomain.com and yourdomain.com by default.